# Small jvectormap height when served through HTTP server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, jvectormap

I am trying to test my jvectormap locally. Previously I was just accessing the HTML file directly through the browser. I recently switched to using an HTTP server to serve the files, but now the map displays with a very small height. The strange thing is, if I resize the browser (bigger or smaller) the map gets larger and larger (doesn't seem to stop expanding). The map when it's initially rendered has a height of 54px.

Setting the `height` CSS attribute for the div I defined to contain the map, as well as the `.jvectormap-container` div, does not help. It it increases the background size, but not the size of the actual map. It is the height in the `<svg>` tag that is actually causing me this issue.

When I access the site again via the file directly, it renders fine. When I do "view source" and access all the files through the HTTP server, they also look fine too. There are no errors in the JS console. I get the same issue on multiple browsers.

Here is my body html:

```
<body>
  <div id="world-map" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;"></div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

And main.js contains

```
var mapDiv = $('#world-map');
mapDiv.vectorMap();
```

Comment: Is your CSS on the page or in a separate file?

Comment: I am defining my own CSS using the `style` attribute for now. But the CSS that comes with jvectormap is in its own file.

Comment: So it's on the page?

Comment: Yes it is on the page.

Comment: I'm not sure how `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;` will behave. Try `top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height:100%;`.

Comment: I just tried it and it has no effect. The original style probably came from an example.

I don't think it is the style on the div that is the problem, because I have tried resizing it, and it does not affect the size of the svg inside it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75482/discussion-between-fractal-and-roamer-1888).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the HTTP server was responding with the incorrect MIME for the JS file.

It would be interesting to know why this would cause this particular problem.